# Storing File Name only in a parameter

Tags: java, string

I have a requirement in which the parameter is coming as file name that upon debugging I have analyzed, as shown below:

```
 private processfile ( string filepath)
 {

 }
```

Now this file path can be like:

```
 C:\abc\file1.txt
    or 
    C:\abc\def\file1.txt
    or 
    C:\ghj\ytr\wer\file1.txt
```

so I have achieved this with as shown below..

```
String p  = new File(filePath).getName();
```

Now the issue is that upon printing the parameter p upon console it prints
file1.txt

whereever I was tring that only the file name to be stored and not the extension, such as
P should only contain file1 only and no extenstion. please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no inbuilt API to to get file name without extension. But why cant you trancate it programmatically like:

```
p = p.substring(0, p.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

What vishal_aim said will work and is correct, but in my opinion it is better to use a library because it will be more expressive and will you won't have to fix all the bugs they've already fixed.  Therefore, you should use this:

[`FilenameUtils.getBaseName(yourFile)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getBaseName%28java.lang.String%29)

Here's what the documentation says:

```
 a/b/c.txt --> c
 a.txt     --> a
 a/b/c     --> c
 a/b/c/    --> ""
```

That last case is something that probably didn't occur to any of us here as a possibility, but the library writers already thought of it for us.